# Match two databases in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two databases, each database has 17 columns and 3238 rows the first one and 3330 rows the second one.
First I read the data from excel:

```
seis <- read.csv("periodo_6.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",row.names=NULL)
siete <- read.csv("periodo_7.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",row.names=NULL)
```

I have created an identifier for every data base

```
attach(seis)
ids <- paste(PROVINCIA,CANTON,PARROQUI,ZONA,SECTOR,sep="")
seis <- cbind(seis,ids)

attach(siete)
ids <- paste(PROVINCIA,CANTON,PARROQUI,ZONA,SECTOR,sep="")
siete <- cbind(siete,ids)
```

Now I want to extract the rows with the same ids. I have proved with merge function

```
uno <- merge(seis,siete,by="ids",all=FALSE)
```

However I have gotten many combinations of the rows with same ids

Then I have tried with match function, but I have two different results

```
d <- na.omit(seis$ids[match(seis$ids,siete$ids)])
d <- na.omit(siete$ids[match(seis$ids,siete$ids)])
```

Comment: There's a format by which you are supposed to provide code here.  Look up what that is.

Comment: It's not really possible for anyone to help without more information about your data, and the specific problem you're having. Specifically, "I have gotten many combinations of the rows with same ids" is quite vague. The best would be to make your example reproducible so that we could run your code ourselves.

Comment: Since you "have gotten many combinations of the rows with same ids" it is highly likely that the ids are not unique in one or both datasets. Type `with(seis,length(unique(ids))==length(ids))` and the same with `seite`. If either is `FALSE`, that's your problem.